# Javascript array integer to string then java string to array

Tags: javascript, java, arrays

need to convert an array of integer(byte) to string in javascript then convert the string to an integer array in java

In javascript, I used `utf-8` and `Uint8Array` to convert an `integer(byte)` array to string, in Java, when I use string.getBytes, I found the converted `integer(byte)` is not the same as the one in javascript

**Javascript part:**

```
var out = gzip.zip('qwertyu');
var enc = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
var arr = new Uint8Array(out);
var testString=enc.decode(arr);
```

Java part:

```
byte[] bytes = testString.getBytes();//here the testString is testString made in javascript
```

In javascript, the array is

```
31, 139,8, 0, 175,60, 19, 93, 0, 3, 43, 44, 79, 45, 42, 169,44, 5, 0, 50, 46, 218,220,7, 0, 0, 0
```

The converted in Java is

```
31, 63, 8, 0, 59, 62, 19, 93, 0, 3, 43, 44, 79, 45, 42, 63, 44, 5, 0, 50, 46, 63, 63, 7, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: What's the `testString`?

Comment: thank you. The string converted in javascript is something I am not enable to copy, something like � I mean, the testString is testString=enc.decode(arr). the string pass from front-end

Comment: Note that Java bytes are signed, i.e. they have a numeric range of [-128,127]

Comment: you gzipped your string, you should ungzip it in java before converting it.

Comment: also, as @Thomas said, any value > 127 results in 63

Comment: Hi, @GrafiCodeStudio, Yes I gzipped my string in javascript, the I get the array "out ", but it is too big to pass it to backend, so I want to compress it to a string, then just pass the string to backend

Comment: @canwang ok, that's the reason why you have � symbols in testString: it's encoded.

Comment: Further note that `String.getBytes()` will use the system's default encoding which might _not_ be UTF-8, so if you expect the string to be UTF-8 encoded you should use `getBytes("UTF-8")` .